# Intervention image exception after environment change

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I have an application built with Laravel 5.3.31 that is using the Intervention image package to resize and put watermarks on pictures. Last week we updated the PHP version from 7.0 to 7.1 and suddenly the upload process provides an **ImageNotReadableException** exception. The php.ini settings were changed properly (post_max_size, memory_limit, etc.) I did a new install, ran composer install and the exception above returns every time a new upload happens. The php-gd extension is installed and the php-fpm and nginx error logs are empty.

Does anybody come up with the same issue?

Thank you for your answers!

Regards,
Gábor

Comment: Any logs inside of `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: It show an exception only Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException: Image source not readable

Comment: The source you are reading the photo from got corrupted or is not supported by upgraded version of intervention library, i suggest you read up docs from intervention library site and compare to see where you might've messed up